# how to remove '#' from url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, .htaccess

My url: eDemo/admin/test/list/#/list

I want: eDemo/admin/test/list

js:

```
var serviceBase ="http://admin-pc/eDemo/admin/test/";
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/add', {
            controller: 'addController',
            templateUrl: serviceBase + 'add',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        })
        .when('/edit', {
            controller: 'editController',
            templateUrl: serviceBase + 'edit',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        })


        .otherwise({ redirectTo : 'list' });
}
```

---

html:

```
<div class='ng-view'></div>
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: @DeepKakkar .. you better do copy the main part of the link code and post in answer section .. It's will remove dependency of that link and the question will have it's answer here ..

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `html5Mode(true)` in your route provider configuration.
Make sure that you are passing the parameter $locationProvider on config function as an argument.

here us the sample js code:

```
var serviceBase ="http://admin-pc/eDemo/admin/test/";
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
     function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/add', {
            controller: 'addController',
            templateUrl: serviceBase + 'add',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        })
        .when('/edit', {
            controller: 'editController',
            templateUrl: serviceBase + 'edit',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        })


        .otherwise({ redirectTo : 'list' });

         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}
```

---

And your HTML should looks like below :

```
<div class='ng-view'>
 <base href="<?=url('/').'/'?>">
</div>
```

Also Keep in mind that never pass `#` in anykind of url like you redirecting , you submitting form through AJAX or anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

At the End of route use:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This should be:

```
var serviceBase ="http://admin-pc/eDemo/admin/test/";
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/add', {
        controller: 'addController',
        templateUrl: serviceBase + 'add',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
    })
    .when('/edit', {
        controller: 'editController',
        templateUrl: serviceBase + 'edit',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }
```

In View File:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the $locationProvider like this

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```